# SSL page iframed in non-SSL page - is form submission still secure?

Tags: forms, security, iframe, ssl

If an SSL page is iframed in a non-SSL page and that SSL page has a form which submits data, is form submission (POST) still secure?

If no, how do I make it secure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

set your form's action explicitely to be "https://..." so it will always go ovet SSL

Answer (score 1):

> If an SSL page is iframed in a non-SSL page and that SSL page has a form which submits data, is form submission (POST) still secure?

Encrypted? yes.

Secure? no.

The parent page can be tampered with by a man in the middle attacker, for example to:

- include a clickjacking attack against the iframe, such as overlaying fake form elements or extracting content (see ‘Next Generation Clickjacking’ for a range of possible attacks)
- change the source of the iframe to somewhere else than the intended HTTPS address - either another unprotected HTTP connection, or  an HTTPS site belonging to the attacker. Browsers do not provide a method of checking the source of an iframe that are usable to the average consumer.

in which case the form contents could be compromised without any indication to the user that the form had not been processed normally.

> If no, how do I make it secure?

The only answer is to use HTTPS for both the parent page and the iframe form.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the form submission from the secure iframe would still be secure having said that you are prone to man in the middle attacks. A javascript injection on the main, non-secure page could compromise the secure iframe.

You will also not get the padlock icon in your browser given the website is not secure (only the iframe is)

Another topic on Stackoverflow explains this: [iframe an SSL secured form on a non SSL site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457921/iframe-an-ssl-secured-form-on-a-non-ssl-site)